# Angular 2: Pass a function to the ngClass tag on the template

Tags: angular, typescript

I have done some searching on this but haven't come across anything that works.

When i pass a function to the ngStyle i get the following error:

`Expression 'getClass()' in ProductView has changed after it was checked.`

My Template looks like:

```
<div class="itemContainer">
    <div class="well imageHolder" [ngClass]="getClass()">
        <img [src]="'img/thumbs/' + item.images[0]" class="productImage" id="productImage">
    </div>
</div>
```

Im not sure what would fix this or even if it can currently be done. I have noticed that this error also occurs with ngStyle.

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: do u know angular or u r jus trying something on ur own??

Comment: What does your getClass function return?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A property binding uses the following syntax: `[someProperty]="an Angular template expression"`.

In your case, the template expression is a function (rather, than, say, a component property).  That's fine.  But according to the "Expression Guidelines" section of the [Template Syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#template-expressions) dev guide, expressions must be "idempotent".  That means that if the

> expression returns a string or a number, it returns the same string or number when called twice in a row. If the expression returns an object (including a `Date` or `Array`), it returns the same object *reference* when called twice in a row.

Since you didn't provide the code for your `getClass()` function, we'll just assume it is violating the idempotent rule.  (You probably return a new array or a new object each time.)

In development mode (which is the default mode), change detection runs twice, and it will catch idempotent violations.

To fix this, return the same array or object reference (but you can modify the array contents or object properties/values).  E.g.,

```
export class MyComponent {
   anArray = [];
   getClass() {
      // manipulate (don't reassign) anArray here, and return it
      return this.anArray;
   }
}
```

Comment: basically Angular2 will dirty-check the return value from previous function return value and compare with the new return value of the method on each change detection cycle (same as it does for property bindings)?

Comment: @kernix, is that a statement or a question?  What you wrote is true/correct.

Answer (score 16):

The answer is simple, you can do that with a function, just make sure the function will return the class name

on html:

```
<div [ngClass]="getClassByValue('a')"> My Div</div>
```

on ts file:

```
  getClassByValue(value: string) {
    switch (value) {
      case "a": return "class-a";
      case "b": return "class-b";
    }
  }
```

will end up with class name "class-a" on your element.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to do this (yes, this probably worked in angular 1.x :) ) The check is there unless you enable production mode:

https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/enableProdMode-function.html

My guess (disclaimer: it is a guess ...) is that you are supposed to set literals/variables that reflect the proper state. A variable does not cause side effects, where a method can. I think they enforce this because it helps you preventing too frequent digest loops.

So this is the way to go:

```
<div class="itemContainer">
    <div class="well imageHolder" [ngClass]="{ 'classA': variableA, 'classB': variableB }">
        <img [src]="'img/thumbs/' + item.images[0]" class="productImage" id="productImage">
    </div>
</div>
```

So instead of running some code on each digest loop that checks if the class should be set (and possibly causes new digest loops by altering other stuff), you should set those variables whenever they need to be set.

Comment: Angular 2 does not run multiple digest loops looking for stability, like Angular 1 did/does.  In dev mode, change detection (digest) does run twice, but only to detect if there were changes, not because it is looking for stability.